# Placement of interface implementation, rules of thumb

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have a number of situations where I have some BaseInterface that gets implemented by a bunch of objects. These objects also typically should implement interfaces such as Serializable or Counatble. Now it's unclear to me on when to have these additional interfaces be specified as being implemented by the classes implementing BaseInterface or when it's better to have BaseInterface extend these additional interfaces. I am looking for an overview of the implications of either approach, and a set of simple rules by which one can determine which approach should be taken in a given situation.

To increase clarity, I provide a simple example in code of both approaches:

Approach 1: Extend the base interface

```
interface BaseInterface extends Countable, Serializable {}

class Implementation implements BaseInterface{}
```

Approach 2: Implement the individual interfaces in the implementations

```
interface BaseInterface {}

class Implementation implements BaseInterface, Countable, Serializable {}
```

It seems that often one want to be able to assume something implementing BaseInterface is Countable, though OTOH this might not be needed and hinder implementation of BaseInterface where implementing Countable is simply not needed. Then there is also the interface segregation principle, which makes me wary of extending interfaces as in approach 1.

Note: This question is on where to put the interface implementation clause. It is not about code sharing via inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution:

```
interface BaseInterface {}

abstract class AbstractBase implements BaseInterface {}

abstract class AbstractBaseCountable implements BaseInterface, Countable {}

abstract class AbstractBaseCountableSerializable implements BaseInterface, Countable, Serializable {}

class Implementation extends AbstractBase/* OR AbstractBaseCountable 
OR AbstractBaseCountableSerializable */ {}
```

Thus, it may create classes with each of the different desired characteristics. Moreover, in certain implementations are abstract classes, so that the implementation classes are cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question in about which approach to take when. Taking both approaches does not really answer it. Also added a note that my question is about on which place something should implement an interface, not on how actual implementation is done - thus your argument about abstract classes is moot.

Comment: Well it is still a good suggestion. You can keep your interfaces segregated and composable (method 1), while still having the convenience of composing them in one place in implementations via class inheritance. The only time you should have interface inheritance is if the extending interface absolutely cannot exist without the extended interface. (E.g. [`OuterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.outeriterator.php) extends [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

Comment: Most importantly, you should never create a new interface solely to compose interfaces--every interface declaration should add a new method. The composition of unrelated interfaces (your "approach 2") pertains to implementation, so use classes to compose them as this answer suggests.